# How can I use change & keyup together

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not working as expected. How can I make this code work in as less lines as possible?

```
$('selector').on('change, keyup', function() {
   // some code 
});
```

Comment: Beware: event selectors are space separated, not comma separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should not be the `,` between the event names

```
$('selector').on('change keyup', function() {
   // some code 
});
```